# Preview not showing while add SPFx app under Communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, communication-site

I have added the SPFx app under the SharePoint Online communication site.

When I tried to create a new page from the Home page and select Apps.

SPFx app preview not showing. Please refer to the below screenshot for a better understanding.

[image]

Can anyone suggest to me how to load a preview of the app on the right side?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enable preview features in SharePoint:

[image]

Please refer to the following documentation:

[Set up the Standard or Targeted release options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/enable-or-disable-preview-features)